# Efficiently retrieving and sorting an object list according to external parameters (Django)

Tags: python, django

In a Django project, I have two lists of tuples. Each tuple in both lists comprises a `(user_id, epoch_time_of_joining)` pair. The first list is a list of **all users**. The second list is a list of **new users**, only containing ids who joined in the past 24 hours. FYI, the list of **all users** contains **new users** too, and both lists are sorted according to `epoch_time_of_joining` (they're actually Redis sorted sets). E.g.:

```
all_users = [('16', 1489044722.035625), ('5', 1489561316.306984), ('104', 1498151886.155885), ('3', 1498158931.476488), ('2', 1498158953.978909)]
new_users = [('3', 1498158931.476488), ('2', 1498158953.978909)]
```

The task is to get a unified object list of all user objects via the Django ORM, such that it's sorted by the newest users first. I also have to paginate the results when they swell beyond 100. Lastly, I have to keep track of the newest users in this unified list, so that I can display a "new" label in front of them in the interface.

What would be the most efficient to accomplish the aforementioned task? I haven't been able to entirely wrap my head around doing it efficiently. I am currently trying:

```
# COMBINE THE TWO LISTS, DROP TIME, BUT KEEP SORTING INTACT
combined_users = []
for (user_id,time) in all_users:
    if (user_id,time) in new_users:
        combined_users.append((user_id,1))
    else:
        combined_users.append((user_id,0))

# GET TUPLE LIST RELEVANT FOR CURRENT PAGE
page_obj = get_page_obj(page_num,combined_users,100)

#RETRIEVE RELEVANT USER OBJECTS
user_objs = User.objects.select_related('userprofile').filter(id__in=[user[0] for user in page_obj.object_list])

# USING NESTED FOR LOOPS TO CREATE FINAL LIST
users = []
    for (user_id,is_new) in page_obj.object_list:
        for user_obj in user_objs:
            if obj.id == user_id:
                users.append((obj,is_new))
```

This works, but it uses nested for loops. The list of users is vast and growing, so I'd prefer a more performant way of executing this. I wonder if I could have somehow used a dictionary here without losing the sorting, but like I said before, it's not coming to me.

Comment: In the line after "#ETRIEVE RELEVANT USER OBJECTS" can't you use order_by function?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: can't use the `order_by()` method since the `User` object in this case doesn't contain the relevant time attribute I need to sort it by. Hence the term "external parameters" in the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets will make your life easier.

```
existing_users = set(all_users) - set(new_users) #  fast but you lose order
sorted_exist_users = ((i[0], False) for i in sorted(existing_users, key=lambda x: x[1]))
new_users = (i[0], True for i in new_users)

batch = []
is_new_flags = []
for i, idx, is_new in enumerate(itertools.chain(new_users, sorted_exit_users)):
     if i % 100:
         batch.append(idx)
         is_new_flags.append(is_new)
     else:
         user_objs = User...filter(id_in=batch)
         yield zip(user_objs, is_new_flags)
         batch, is_new_flags = [], []
```

Comment: Cool, but would it help reduce the **O(n^2)** I'm currently incurring due to the nested for loops?

Comment: Yes it's nlogn, only because of the sort.

Comment: Won't I still need to retrieve the object list from the DB and then map it onto `new_users+sorted_exist_users` via a nested for loop?

Comment: If you're filtering by user_id I don't think you need that last step but you think you need it then it's simply the set intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this would work or not. Select all user objects, sort them and then select user profiles

```
user_objs = User.objects.filter(id__in=[user[0] for user in page_obj.object_list]).order_by('some_param')

user_profile_obj = user_objs.select_related('userprofile')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **[in_bulk()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk)** could help reduce the processing from **O(n^2)** to **O(n)**, owing to the fact that it returns:

> ... a dictionary mapping (of) each primary-key value to an instance of the
>   object with the given ID

Notice how it changes the tail-end of the implementation:

```
#RETRIEVE RELEVANT USER OBJECTS
user_objs = User.objects.select_related('userprofile').in_bulk([user[0] for user in page_obj.object_list])

# USING ONE FOR LOOP TO CREATE THE FINAL LIST
users = []
    for (user_id,is_new) in page_obj.object_list:
        users.append((user_objs[user_id],is_new))
```

Moreover, passing `map(itemgetter(0),page_obj.object_list)` to `in_bulk()` could be another optimization.